# Heroku application crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, mlab, heroku-cli

Application Error in Heroku , with status H10 , desc = "app crashed" , No error in logs , Application running Locally but after deploying and building successfully , App is Crashing.

Methods I had tried to run it :-

1. including procfile
2. including start script (node server.js)
3. changing npm version in package.json from 5.6.x to 5.7.1
4. setting NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false to install dev-dependencies
5. setting process.env.MONGOLAB_AMBER_URI as on using mlab addons

Github repo = https://github.com/Emir28107/imgLoader.git

Application domain = https://imcha.herokuapp.com/

`heroku logs --tail` file content

[image: Link To Heroku logs --tail]

As , Build is successful , What might causing app to crash ? Help me please

Answer (score 2):

we had an issue that might not be similar to yours but we were not getting any useful info from the logs with regards to the reason for the app crash.

However if you run `heroku run rails console` it gave a more specific error, which helped us resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined port specifically, Heroku is trying to start the project on the different port.

```
var port = process.env['PORT'] || 3000;
```

Comment: I had used app.set("port" , process.env.PORT || 3000); and in listen app.get("port")  , but still commit the change as per your answer sir , still  i m getting application error .

Comment: Change main from index.js to server.js in your package.json file.

Comment: In package.json , there is already a script tag consisting node server.js as start object